# How to remove pixi.js banner from the console?

Tags: javascript, console, devtools, pixi.js

After seeing it for 1000 times it gets annoying so I'd like to have option to remove it.

Somebody online answered that setting

```
PIXI.dontSayHello = true;
```

will solve the problem in older versions of PIXI, but in version 3.0.3 it didn't work. Searching for "dontSayHello" in the source code didn't render any results.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is deprecated in newer versions:

`PIXI.utils._saidHello = true;`

This is right:

`PIXI.utils.skipHello();`

Answer (score 4):

After looking in the source code of Pixi I found that an easy way to disable the banner is to add this line just after pixi.js  embed

```
<script>PIXI.utils._saidHello = true;</script>
```

Comment: Note that despite the underscore, it's an officially documented feature: https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/blob/ace34bfeec0a5035c50555f3fb1c84a78eb8d246/src/core/utils/index.js#L93

Answer (score 3):

You can do this is you are using import statements:

```js
import { utils } from 'pixi.js';
utils.skipHello();
```